# Update not equal and Null

Tags: mysql

It must be dead simple, but I'm hitting the roof on this one.

I have a table

```
   A      B        C
-------------------------
|  1  |   9   |   car   |
|  2  |  NULL |   bike  |
|  3  |   6   |   NULL  |
|  4  |   7   |   car   |
|  5  |   9   |   dog   |
|  6  |  NULL |   cat   |
|  7  |  NULL |   NULL  |
```

I like to UPDATE al rows where B != 9 or C != car. In this exampe it should update rows 2, 3, 6 and 7.

I've tried multiple combinations of WHERE clauses, but either it updates all rows or it updates none of them.

Some of the things I tried:

```
//updates none
UPDATE table SET A=9,B=7,C="mouse" WHERE B<=>"99" OR C<=>"auto"
//updates all rows
UPDATE table SET A=9,B=7,C="mouse" WHERE (B<=>"99" OR B IS NOT NULL) OR (C<=>"auto" OR C IS NOT NULL)
//updates all
UPDATE table SET A=9,B=7,C="mouse" WHERE B IS NULL OR B<=>"99" OR C IS NULL OR C<=>"auto"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, all of the answers have neglected the painfully-simple `<=>`  null-safe equality operator.

```
WHERE (NOT B <=> 9)
  AND (NOT C <=> 'car');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Also, it bears mentioning that there's a perfectly good reason why this is necessary since nothing is ever actually truly equal to or not equal to `NULL`, including another null:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

Answer (score 3):

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5812/1):

```
UPDATE table
SET A=9, B=7, C='mouse'
WHERE (B != 9     OR B IS NULL)
  AND (C != 'car' OR C IS NULL)
```

SQL standard has `IS DISTINCT FROM` operator which treats `NULL` as comparable value, but unfortunately MySQL does not support it. With it, your query would have been:

```
UPDATE table
SET A=9, B=7, C='mouse'
WHERE B IS DISTINCT FROM 9
  AND C IS DISTINCT FROM 'car'
```

(this works in PostgreSQL).

Comment: When I split the WHERE clause in two, it works. `B!='9' OR B IS NULL` and `C!='car OR C IS NULL` separate give good results. But combined they still not work.

Comment: Give the man a drink! Spend some hours on that last night, overseeing the `AND`. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

This should be

```
UPDATE table SET A=9,B=7,C='mouse' 
WHERE (B !='9' or B is null) 
and  (C!='car' or C is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET A=9,B=7,C="mouse" WHERE B IS NULL OR C IS NULL
```

Comment: I need more than only the NULL fields